# Getting Previous object in Callbacks Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, callback

```Rails
    before_save
     old_mode = previous_instance.mode
     new_mode = new_instance.mode

     if old_mode != new_mode 
        do_something
     end

    end
    
    def mode

      if field1 == 'something' && field2 == 'otherthing'
       return 'mode1'
      end
      
      if field3 == 'something' && associated_record.field == 'anyotherthing'
        
        return 'mode2'
      end
    end
  
  if field3 == 'something' && associated_record.field == 'anyotherthing'
    
    return 'mode2'
  end
end
```

What I need to do if I want to call the instance method on the previous instance and a new instance in the callback? As you can see in the code the method is calculating the mode on the basis of field and associated record field values and I want to get the previous model and new mode. I know that the '_was'/'changes' method is available to get previous values but this is a very small example of a mode function I have a lot of fields and associated records dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is the proper way, but it should work.

Use the attr_accessor,
Eg:

```
class Example

  attr_accessor: old_mode

  before_save
    if old_mode && old_mode != mode 
      do_something
    end
  end
  
  def attributes=(attribs)
    @old_mode = mode
    super
  end
    
  def mode
    do_calculation
  end
end
```

Or you can go without the `attributes=` method, at the place you call the save/update, before assign the attributes, call `example.old_mode = mode`

Comment: I tried and it has worked I will test all the cases now. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, :).